# UI font has rendering glitches in GNOME Shell

Tags: gnome, fonts

I don't really know how to describe this problem in English.

A picture can say more than words - look at the tabs at the top of the image. The current font settings are shown as well.

[image: unclear patchy fonts in window tab titles, font settings window showing Ubuntu fonts]

I don't know what basic info I should provide so if something missing, please tell me.

Ubuntu 12.04

GNOME Shell 3.4.1

---

I know a reboot can make everything normal but I'm looking for a more permanent solution that can fix this problem (or bug).

---

Update

Thanks for Fitoschido, I finally know what keyword I could use for googling. I think it's a bug of gnome shell.

https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/34847